# Best way of sending an email from the result of a PHP script

Tags: php

I have to build a html email. The email will pull data out of my database, fill in the email with HTML code to display the data to the user, with linkbuttons to send a GET request to a PHP page which will react according to the choice the user made (which button they pressed).

Now I am able to send an HTML email already. However, this particular email will be a lot bigger, will contain CSS (but no javascript) etc.

I don't want to be building a huge HTML string by hand... It'll be completely impossible to debug. What I would like to do instead is get the results of my PHP file into a string and use this as the email body. I'm pretty sure it's possible to do, but I'm still relatively a beginner when it comes to web development.

My code would make this post way too long, but let's go with something like this as an example:

---

**emailSource.php**:

```
<?php
    include_once "init.php";
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <span>One-Two, </span>
        <?php
            echo "testing";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

When I try to send my email, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
sendMail("my subject", emailSource.php?myparam=42, "myEmail@myDomain.com");
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now this syntax obviously isn't valid, but that should help you understand what I'm trying to do.

Thank you,

Mathieu Turcotte

Comment: "I don't want to be building a huge HTML string by hand..." is a valid concern. The solution is to use a template-driven email service. Most modern third-party solutions use an API and allow you to separate your data from your final HTML presentation using placeholders.

Comment: I doubt placeholders will be good enough here as the report can get quite big. There are multiple tables being built, with a varying number of rows. Using placeholders for this will be a nightmare. Would have worked if it was a simpler report, but I doubt it'll be my best bet here, unless I'm not getting what you mean correctly?

Comment: A template, even a complicated one, will always be far simpler than the "HMTL string" version.

Comment: Instead of a URL, you could call a _function_, passing in the desired value, and have that function return the email body.

Comment: Output buffering is what you're looking for. See @ChandrashekarSingh's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by exactly what you asked, you can use output buffering:

```
<?php
   //start buffering output (Everything that was supposed to go to the browser is instead stored)
   ob_start();
   ?> 
   <html>
       <!-- write lots of HTML, including some data from db -->
       <div><?php echo $data; ?></div>
   </html>
   <?php
   //get the data that was buffered
   $big_html_message = ob_get_clean();

   mail($to, $subject, $big_html_message);
```

Comment: Do note that OP wants to avoid doing strings.. after `ob_start();` just close the PHP with `?>` and do a regular HTML without doing any `echo`. Then re-open with a new PHP tag `<?php` afterwards to continue with `ob_get_clean();`.

Comment: So what do you have in mind then, when I save my object, in it's save() function, I would add a curl request to that php page, which would take care of building AND sending the email, and never be displayed on the website?

What I had in mind was to use a php file as the sorce of the email, but this should also work!

I'm leaving work in a couple minutes. I've upvoted your answer, I will test this out on monday, I'll accept the answer if it works :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: uom-pgregorio: Thanks for your comment. This is exactly what I was going to do anyway, as this is how I usually do my PHP pages. It's a mix of PHP and HTML, but I very rarely echo HTML code from PHP. I just switch between PHP and HTML :) but thats a lot for the help! It's much appreciated! (When I discovered you could not only switch from PHP to HTML and back at will, that you can even make a IF in php, then go back to HTML, and close the PHP if later.. which puts the HTML inside the IF... That was a revelation! lol)

Comment: Chandrashekar, your solution worked very, very well! Whenever I shout "FIRST TRY!" in the office, you know it's a good day! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to separate the view ( html ) and the logic code ( php ),you can create templates and view function/class to include them, example :

template.php :

```
<html>
    <body>
       Hello, <?= $this->get('name'); ?>.
       <?php if $this->has('date') : ?>
         Year : <?= $this->get('date')->format('Y'); ?>
       <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

view.php :

```
class View extends ArrayObject {

    public function get(string $id) 
    {
        return $this->offsetGet($id);
    }

    public function set(string $id,$value): void
    {
        $this->offsetSet($id,$value);
    }

    public function has(string $id): bool
    {
        return $this->offsetExists($id); 
    }

    public function remove(string $id): void
    {
        $this->offsetUnset($id);
    }

    public function render(string $template): string
    {
       ob_start();
       require $template;
       return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

usage :

```
require_once('view.php');

$view = new View();
$view->set('name','AzJezz');
$view->set('date',new DateTime());
$html = $view->render('template.php');

sendMail('Subject !',$html,'someone@gmail.com');
```

Comment: Your answer is perfectly valid! Thank you! I have upvoted it, but I ended up going with Chandrashekar's solution. But thank you for your help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: my solution would be perfect if you are going to use this in multiple pages, to make sure that you don't have messy pages with html and php combined, but if you are looking for more complex tempting engine , check out twig. https://twig.symfony.com

Answer (score -1):

This is fairly simple to do if you request `emailSource.php` as a separate HTTP request:

```
sendMail(
    "my subject",
    file_get_contents( 'http://example.com/emailSource.php?myparam=42' ),
    "myEmail@myDomain.com"
);
```

Comment: That doesn't evaluate the PHP, it just dumps in the raw PHP source.

Comment: I don't know if this will work, as MonkeyZeus said, but I'll try this too on Monday as this solution looks really easy. Kinda looks too good to be true, but it does work, it would be awesome!

Comment: @MathieuTurcotte My aim was definitely for simplicity. Let me know how it works for you!

Comment: Making a request to fetch content that you're going to inline is a really heavy-handed way of doing it. Chandrashekar Singh's solution is a lot more elegant.